# Validation callout direction issue in Arabic

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, validation

I am facing problem with the validationcallout Ajax extender.

I am working on the Arabic versions of webpages, so page alignment will be from right-left,  and I am calling the validation errors using the validationcallout extender, where I am facing a problem the direction.

In this error, you can notice that the alignment is not proper. I tried changing the direction using CSS, but I failed to achieve the correct form.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.customCalloutStyle .ajax__validatorcallout_callout_arrow_cell {
    padding: 18px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 1px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.customCalloutStyle .ajax__validatorcallout_callout_arrow_cell .ajax__validatorcallout_innerdiv {
    font-size: 1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}

.customCalloutStyle .ajax__validatorcallout_callout_arrow_cell .ajax__validatorcallout_innerdiv div{
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```